# support for-each in custom class swift

Tags: swift

I'm objective-c guy, that sometimes learns swift and try to build swift classes in my projects.
I am trying to create "for-each" to custom class that holds a private array.

1. Do I need to create Iterator ? If yes do I need to make it class variable and what type it is ?
2. Any sample code or help in this code will be nice.

```
import Foundation  
@objcMembers class FeedItemsCollection:NSObject,Sequence, IteratorProtocol {   
    private var feedItems:[FeedItem]  
    private var feedsIterator = //stuck  
    public init(feedItems : [FeedItem])
    {
        self.feedItems = feedItems
    }

    func add(feedItems: [FeedItem]) {
        self.feedItems.append(contentsOf: feedItems)
    }

    func add(feedItems: [FeedItem], at:Int) {
        self.feedItems.insert(contentsOf: feedItems, at: at)
    }

    func next() -> FeedItem? {        
        return feedsIterator.next ////stuck 
    }
}
```

I call the code from objective-c in this way :

```
self.feedItemsCollection = [[FeedItemsCollection alloc] initWithFeedItems:entities];

    for(FeedItem * feedItem in self.feedItemsCollection)
    {
        NSLog(@"feedItem-title = %@", feedItem.title);
    }
```

Comment: How much of the functionality of `Sequence` do you actually need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for calling **from** *objective-c* with *for-each* to *swift class*,
is by changing the Array to NSArray and implement NSFastEnumeration.

```
@objcMembers public class FeedItemsCollection:NSObject,NSFastEnumeration,Sequence
{
    //private var feedItems:[FeedItem]
    private var feedItems:NSMutableArray

    public init(feedItems :NSMutableArray)
      {
          self.feedItems = feedItems
      }
    public func makeIterator() ->NSFastEnumerationIterator
    {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
    public func countByEnumerating(with state: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSFastEnumerationState>, objects buffer: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, count len: Int) -> Int {

        return self.feedItems.countByEnumerating(with: state, objects: buffer, count: len);
    }

}
```

and the objective-c code that call for-each loop

```
   self.feedItemsCollection = [[FeedItemsCollection alloc] initWithFeedItems:entities];

    for(FeedItem * feedItem in self.feedItemsCollection)
    {
        NSLog(@"feedItem-title = %@", feedItem.title);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what functionality you need, you can implement some or all of the protocols below, all just forwarding to `feedItems`:

```
import Foundation

struct FeedItem {}

@objcMembers class FeedItemsCollection: NSObject {
    private var feedItems:[FeedItem]

    override init() {
        self.feedItems = []
    }
}

extension FeedItemsCollection: Sequence {
    func makeIterator() -> Array<FeedItem>.Iterator {
        return feedItems.makeIterator()
    }
}

extension FeedItemsCollection: Collection {
    typealias Index = Int

    var startIndex: Index { feedItems.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Index { feedItems.endIndex }

    func index(after i: Index) -> Index { self.feedItems.index(after: i) }

    subscript(_ i: Index) -> FeedItem {
        get { self.feedItems[i] }
        set { self.feedItems[i] = newValue }
    }
}

extension FeedItemsCollection: BidirectionalCollection {
    func index(before i: Index) -> Index { self.feedItems.index(before: i) }
}

extension FeedItemsCollection: RandomAccessCollection {}

extension FeedItemsCollection {
    // Not strictly necessary, but IIRC it improves indexing performance.

    func index(_ index: Index, offsetBy offset: Int) -> Index {
        self.feedItems.index(index, offsetBy: offset)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I need to change your code and add lot of "public" so it compile. but I have warning in the for-each code (the objc code that use the swift class :
"Collection expression type 'FeedItemsCollection *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'" update. test it and boom crash.

I can "struggle" to fix this, but this is the reason I only want  the methods that support the "for-each" no less, no more.

Comment: @user1105951 That's why I asked which functionality you actually needed, but you didn't answer. Supporting for-each loops just requires conformance to `Sequence`.

Comment: but I have warning+crash.
can you complete the countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count ?

Comment: @user1105951 I don't know how you're calling it, so I can't really help unless I see what you're trying

Comment: I thought that's obvious, but if not, I updated the code in the question. thanks.

Comment: I made another test. calling for-each from swift works ok. calling the for-each from objective-c (what I need) , get warning "Collection expression type 'FeedItemsCollection *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'", and crash if I call it.

Comment: @user1105951 Oh, you're calling it from Objective C. You should have made that clear :p Objective C uses a very different system to implement its for-each loops (which it calls "fast enumeration"). It has a rather odd API design, motivated by the need to reduce message sends. It's designed so that only 1 message is sent per batch, rather than 1 per element, which is critical in tight loops https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfastenumeration But it also means that's kind of clunky to implement, especially in swift